# when adding or editing product in opencart it just redirect to root of site

Tags: opencart2.x

I installed opencart, after months adding and editing product, now i can't edit or insert product to my website.

> I use opencart 2.0.3.1

```
when i tringy to edite or add a product it just redirect to root of site .
and i check my user roles,my user is admin .
```

Comment: Did you do a little bit of debugging? Did you tried to echo inside your POST?

Comment: actually the error i got is an unusual thing. becuase a few days a go i simply add and edit my product in opencart correctly . but in 2 days ago, when i try to edit or add an product to opencart in my admin panel, is just redirect to root of my website .
in other section of my admin panel every things is ok , for example i can edit or add categories.

Comment: can you give me the link, username and password so that I can debug? If u feel comfortable.

Comment: yes.please send your email address to me farhad00niaz[at]gmail.com

Comment: ali.zia.1991@gmail.com

Comment: the admin panel langue is Persian

Answer (score -1):

For now i just fonded that when i using html in description about Product it happens

for example:

```html
<div class="description_">
<span class="feauter"> Metal</span>
<p>
line <br/>
line <br/>
line <br/>
</p>
</div>
```

bout this html codes worked in past !! I dont know Why it dose not work now!!!